# Help me pair with multiple Android devices using HM-10 BLE

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy, arduino-uno

I have a simple home automation project using an Arduino, HM-10 and relay to switch ON/OFF a connected load using an app made in Kodular (free online APP creation site.)

The HM-10 BLE module is connected to the Arduino. I found out that the HM-10 BLE module that I was using was a cheap clone.

I found a workaround [tutorial](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/how-to-flash-genuine-hm-10-firmware-on-cc2541-make-genuine-hm-10-from-cc41/379343) to upload the genuine firmware to the BLE chip, which I did successfully. Now HM-10 follows the original AT commands provided in the [datasheet.](https://people.ece.cornell.edu/land/courses/ece4760/PIC32/uart/HM10/DSD%20TECH%20HM-10%20datasheet.pdf)

Everything was working fine until I encountered a problem which I can't get through.

Since I was using this project for my home and my family members, I wanted it to be secured. I secured it using the AT command "AT+TYPE3" which enables authentication via PIN and thereafter bonding so that it's one time pairing and bonding process for person (my family) knowing the PIN. When I reconnect using Android_1 it connects fast without asking me PIN again, making connection process seamless.

When I connect using other Android_2 to it asks for PIN and then bonds as expected. When I try to reconnect using Android_1 it seems to forget the previous pairing and asks for PIN and pairing once again.

In a nutshell, when I pair an Android_1 it asks for PIN one time and after that it remembers that pairing. No matter how many times I reconnect. When an Android_2 pairs with it, it seems to forget the previous pairing with Android_1. This vicious loop continues.

Can anyone help me with this problem so that the  HM-10 doesn't forget the devices with which it was paired previously? I also have tested with classic Bluetooth module HC-05, but I never encountered this problem. It seems to remember all the previously paired devices.

Comment: what is your specific question? ... this is a Q&A site, not a chat forum

Comment: Why don't HM-10 remember the device it has paired with? Once it gets paired with another device it kind of forgets the previous device it has paired with.
@jsotola I know its not chat forum. But I wanted to include all the relevant information so that people won't complain that they can't help me due to lack of information.